# Swagger UI Description

Tags: c#, swagger

```
    /// <summary>
    /// This method will retrieve a company in portal
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="UserName">This is the Username assigned to a company to allow service procesing</param>
    /// <param name="ActualCompanyName">Actual Name of the company</param>
    /// <returns>This returns a PortalCompany object <see cref="PortalCompany"/> upon successful completion.  If a failure arises it will return <see cref="SiteAccessException"/> object.  The restful nodes will return</returns>

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
        UriTemplate = "GetCompany/{UserName}/{ActualCompanyName}")]
    [SwaggerWcf.Attributes.SwaggerWcfPath("Get Company", "Get Company to the portal")]
    PortalCompany GetCompany(String UserName, String ActualCompanyName);
```

Here's My Operation Contract. I need to View the Description in this section. See Image for reference where it should appear.

[Swagger UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c77R3.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for description of parameters, not the end-point one.

If you need to show the description on any `DataContract` property, your should add `DescriptionAttribute` on them:

```
[DataContract(Name = "book")]
public class MyContract
{
    [DataMember(Name = "UserName")]
    [Description("Name of the user")]
    public string UserName{ get; set; }

    // [.......]
}
```

You should take a look at the documentation for better undestanding of those parameters:[SwaggerWcf](https://github.com/abelsilva/swaggerwcf)

Comment: Thank You so much. How about whether the value is required or not?

Comment: @Athan there's a exemple in the docs covering required fields

Comment: Thanks you. Yeah actually already did it man, Cheers. On more thing please. How to change the "Required" label inside the textbox to "Optional" for example?